# Dropdowns not working in Dreamweaver fluid grid layout

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am working on building a website using Dreamweavers fluid grid layout.

There are two drop-downs in my navigation (`About Rick +`, and `Media +`) -- they don't work in fluid grid layout but work fine in a regular html document.

Built in fluid grid layout: http://zutterdesign.com/rztest/
Built with regular HTML: http://zutterdesign.com/rztest/navtest.html

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.